# Meteor collection of task module not found

Tags: meteor

This is my first time trying meteor and I am following : https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections. I am keep getting module not found. I am following the collection tutorial not sure what am i doing wrong? Please help. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to import `tasks.js` (with a plural **s**) whereas your file is `task.js` (singular)

Comment: Can't believe i lost 2 hours because of typo. Thanks :)